# 3 way light switches with gfci

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, garage

I am wiring my detached garage lights, I want to make the connections at the ceiling with plugin outlets to plug lights into. I am installing 3 way switches. If I install a dead front gfci (or gfci circuit breaker in breaker box) up stream of the switch will it work correctly?

Comment: Give us a design diagram and you'll get some feedback.  Otherwise, all I see here is a list of parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine. You can't put a GFCI in the ceiling. But receptacles in a garage need GFCI protection, so any place before the switch:

- GFCI/breaker
- GFCI/deadfront
- GFCI/receptacle

is fine. I prefer hardwired lights. But if for some reason plug-in lights are desired, a GFCI/receptacle *next to the first switch* makes the most sense to me. You can never have too many receptacles.

Comment: The gfci dead front is probably the way I will go, lights will be on there own circuits. I wanted the accessibility to move lights easily if I decided something different later. The garage is 32x60.   Thanks for the help.